# Laravel 5.1 Foreign Key Trouble

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5.1

I have some trouble getting the foreign key.

My Migrations looks like this (shortened them):

```
    <?php

    class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {


    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->integer('number_of_chapters');
            $table->text('input_mpg');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('products');
    }
}

<?php

    class CreateChaptersTable extends Migration
    {

        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();   
                $table->time('input-chapter-start1');
                $table->time('input-chapter-end1');
                $table->timestamps();

            });

            Schema::table('chapters', function($table) {
                $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            });
        }

        public function down()
        {
            Schema::drop('chapters');
        }
    }
```

And my 2 Model like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chapters extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'chapters';

    protected $fillable = ['input-chapter-start1', 'input-chapter-end1'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

}
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Product extends Model
    {

        protected $table = 'products';

        protected $fillable = ['email', 'title', 'filename', 'inputMpg', 'number_of_chapters'];

        public static $rules = [
            'email'                => 'required|email|max:50',
            'title'                => 'required|max:50',
            'filename'             => 'required|max:50',
            'input_mpg'            => 'required'
        ];

        public function Chapters()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Chapters');
        }

    }
```

And just save it like this in my Controller

```
$product->save();
$Chapters->save();
```

And get following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`generator`.`chapters`, CONSTRAINT `chapters_product_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`)) (SQL: insert
>   into `chapters` (`input-chapter-start1`, `input-chapter-end1`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (12:12:12, 12:12:12, 2016-04-25
>   11:41:31, 2016-04-25 11:41:31))

**EDIT**
Controller looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


class ProductController extends Controller
{

    protected $request;

    public function request(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function createProduct(Request $request)
    {

        $product        = new Product;
        $Chapters       = new Chapters($request->all());

        $data              = $request->all();
        $projectEmail      = $request->input('email');
        $projectTitle      = $request->input('title');
        $projectFile       = $request->input('filename');
        $projectChapters   = $request->input('number_of_chapters');

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Product::$rules);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

        $product->fill($data);

        if($product->save())
        {

            $Chapters->product()->associate($product);
            $Chapters->save();
            return redirect()->route('root')->with('message', 'success')->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('newProduct')->with('message', 'Error')->withInput();
        }

    }

}
```

**Edit I tried Samsquanch suggestion:
And added this in my controller:**

```
$product->save();

$Chapters->product()->associate($product);

$Chapters->save();
```

but still get this error message:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2093: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not telling Laravel or MySQL what the foreign key should be.

You have two options here (both from the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)

The first option would be to save `chapters` through `product`:

```
$chapters = $product->chapters()->saveMany($Chapters); // or just->save() if it's only one
```

The second (and how I generally do it) would be to use `associate()` which relies on the `belongsTo` relationship in your Chapters model:

```
$product->save();

$Chapters->product()->associate($product);

$Chapters->save();
```

There's also a third, but not recommended, option of just setting the foreign key yourself manually.

Edit:

```
$product->chapters()->associate($Chapters);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer (sorry for the late reply) I am going to check it out

Comment: Either method is in the controller, you shouldn't have to touch the models.

Comment: I get this at the moment `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::product()`

Comment: Are you trying to use the second approach?

Comment: First tried the second approach, then I tried the first one where I get nearly the same message `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::chapters()`

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? It looks like either the models aren't set up right or you're not using them correctly in the controller.

Comment: That's all of the code for the models, I'll add the controller wait a minute

Comment: This line `$Chapters->$product->product()->associate($product);` should be `$Chapters->product()->associate($product);`. Give that a try.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to tell you, it was before like you said `$Chapters->product()->associate($product);` then I tried out that current line, the errors keeps being, edited it now like you said

Comment: See my edit, try `$product->chapters()->associate($Chapters);` instead. I may have done the association backwards.

Comment: Thank you, strange I get this message now
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::chapters()`

Comment: That may be a casing issue, `public function Chapters()` -- make `Chapters()` lowercase in your model.

Comment: did it nothing changes

Comment: The code should work. It seems like your issues are coming from the model for some reason, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Can you just call `$product->chapters` from your controller without any errors?

Comment: ooh you were right thanks alot, I had a little syntax mistake, it works perfectly now.